# Is there a fast way to get the index of bit which equal 1 in a binary value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I want to get the index which equals to 1 in binary format, now I use codes like this:

```
inline static uint8_t the_index(uint32_t val){
  return uint8_t(log(val & ((~val) + 1))/log(2));
}
```

I want to know if there are other ways to achieve the same target?  Is there any possible to use bit operation to solve this problem?

I do this to iterater a value and build some operations which depends on the position iterated, the pesudo codes like this:

```
 while (temp) {
            auto cur_index = the_index(temp);
            auto window = ((1 << i) - 1) << cur_index;
            if (((temp & window) ^ window) == 0) {
              //....do something
            }
            temp &= temp - 1;
        }
```

Comment: Can the value have more than one bit set? In that case, what do you want to happen?

Comment: Yes, The value have more than one bit set. I want to iterate it and know the position iterated.

Comment: Sounds like [`std::countr_zero`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countr_zero)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: The `log` code suggests finding the Most Significant Bit set. That's `std::bit_width`.

Comment: @MSalters `val & ((~val) + 1)` zeroes all bits except the least significant `1`.

Comment: Do you have statistics? In particular, do you have a rough idea how many bits are set? If most bits are zero, it can be advantageous to first test whole bytes, and only check non-zero bytes.

Comment: Until C++20, `countr_zero` is availabe in Boost.Core; live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/hvdx9x6PE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a standard function for this:

```
auto cur_index = std::countr_zero(temp);
```

On my system, this compiled down to:

```
xor     eax, eax
tzcnt   eax, edi
```

Note that this function successfully counts the zero bits from right until first one bit whether the input has exactly one set bit or not.

Comment: Yes, from c++20.

Answer (score 4):

If the question is about finding the index of a single bit in a value, say `uint32_t x = b000010000;`, one quick method is to

```
auto index = builtin_popcount(x - 1);

// example: b000010000 - 1
//          b000001111
// popcount(b000001111) == 4
```

In arm64 architecture the best method would be to use the count_leading_zero(x) instruction/operation, due to lack of fast popcount for general purpose registers.

Reading the OP more carefully, it's not guaranteed that `x` only has one bit set -- the question seems to be rather finding the index of the least significant bit set. That can be isolated with

```
 x = temp & (0-temp);
```

Comment: On arm64 (without c++20) the fast method is to use `count_leading_zero(bit_reverse(temp))`, where `temp` can have multiple bits set.

Comment: auto temp = 0x08; auto x = temp & (0-temp); these codes got x which equals to 8.

Comment: Yes, is there a question? Given any non-zero variable `temp`, the least significant bit is isolated by `temp & (-temp)`. When `temp` only contains a single bit, then `x == temp`. This bit can be also used later to `temp ^= x;` to toggle it off.
Since unary minus `-uint32_t` is UB or ill-formed, the correct way to handle it is to write it as (0-temp);

Comment: That can get the least significant bit, but how to get its index? Would you like to give me the entire codes,  thanks!

Comment: That is covered in the first paragraph, and that is `auto index = builtin_popcount(x - 1);`
Also with intel intrinsics, you can use `int _bit_scan_reverse (temp);` directly. The output will be undefined if `temp == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `__builtin_ctzl` : Returns the number of trailing 0-bits in x, starting at the least significant bit position. (warning: If x is 0, the result is undefined).

examples : __builtin_ctzl(0x10) = 4, __builtin_ctzl(0x20) = 5

For your case you could just use it like :

```
unsigned index;
do {
    index = temp ? __builtin_ctzl(temp) : 0;
    ... //do your stuff
    temp -= pow(2, index);
} while (index);
```

Comment: I think OP is doing a very good job already in clearing the least significant bit with `temp &= temp - 1`.